# How to calculate the volume of a 0.1 M NaOH(aq) solution necessary to make a 0.5 M EDTA solution with pH = 8?

Tags: homework, experimental-chemistry, titration

I was told that EDTA dissolves at a pH of $8$. Therefore I need to use a base to increase the pH to $8$ is what I understand. How exactly would I go about this?

In my head I if I wanted $1~\mathrm{L}$ of $0.5~\mathrm{M}$ EDTA I would take $186.12~\mathrm{g}$ of the EDTA, since its molar mass is $M = 372.24~\mathrm{g\,mol^{-1}}$.

Then I would add $800~\mathrm{mL}$ of distilled $\ce{H2O}$ to dissolve it, but since it wont be at $\ce{pH}=8$, it wont dissolve.

So I assumed I would just add it drop wise until it dissolved while spinning? I lack access to a burrette and only have a crappy pH meter to check pH.

One I observe the EDTA dissolved I simply add up to $1000~\mathrm{mL}$?

**I just wish I had a way to figure out how much $\ce{NaOH}$ I needed to add to dissolve the EDTA** so I wouldn't have to do it drop wise.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the concentration of a sodium hydroxide solution with a pH of 8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I saw this on the researchgate.net website:

> I followed this procedure for preparing  0.5M EDTA ph8(100ml) . Initially I  warmed around 70ml of water and added an ml of 6MNaoh solution to shoot up the ph to 7.6  with the container on  a hot plate .Then I slowly added the measured quantity of EDTA and Simultaneously kept adding small volumes of 6M Naoh solution while measuring  the ph.Finally around ph 8 the EDTA was completely dissolved and the process was way too quick.."
>
> - Bhavani Nagarajan · University of North Texas HSC at Fort Worth